# Shortcut a workflow

Tags: workflow, item-deleted

I have a list workflow which last step is to **delete the item itself**. 
It works fine, but it leaves *orphan workflow* (that is workflow still running even if it has lost its item). I am afraid **it would cause problems** (I had already issues with creating new forms and maybe this was the cause).
Does anybody has a good suggestion how to solve it or a workaround?
Currently the **2013 list WF** is calling a **2010 list WF** which deletes the item.
I have tried replacing the deleting list WF with a **site WF**, but the issue is not solved.
Is there a way to **force workflow not to wait the end of a step?** I can figure to delay of some second the deleting workflow in order to give time to the main one to finish...